# Using Promise all to fill dropdowns

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using Promises to automatically fill up my dropdowns on page load (I have multiple dropdowns on the page).

Here is the code I use to return the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urls = ['getBrands', 'getTags'];
    Promise.all(urls.map(u=>fetch(u))).then(
        responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
    ).then(
        texts=>console.log(texts)
    ).then(
        result => console.log(result[0]) //This is where the error is
    )
});
```

This prints the response to the console correctly, but throws an error when I try to read the individual result. The error is `Uncaught(in promise) TypeError: cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: `console.log(texts)` will return `undefined`.

Comment: You get this error when url is not formed properly. var urls = ['getBrands', 'getTags'] is the problem in your case, kindly recheck it in console window.

Comment: @yogihosting that is  not the problem in this case. *This prints the response to the console correctly* — that could not happen if the URLs were wrong.

Comment: Another way to deal with the issue of adding `console.log` in the middle of a chain of `then`s is to replace it with a function like `const log = (arg) => {console.log(arg); return arg;}`.  I often use a more general-purpose one like `const tap = (sideEffect) => (arg) => {sideEffect (arg); return arg}` and then use `.then (tap (console .log))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your first fulfillment handler returns `undefined`, which becomes the fulfillment value of the promise it returns.

If you just remove it, your second fulfillment handler will see the values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urls = ['getBrands', 'getTags'];
    Promise.all(urls.map(u=>fetch(u))).then(
        responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
    ).then(
        result => console.log(result[0])
    )
});
```

Alternatively, have it return what it receives:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urls = ['getBrands', 'getTags'];
    Promise.all(urls.map(u=>fetch(u))).then(
        responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
    ).then(texts => {
        console.log(texts);
        return texts;
    }).then(
        result => console.log(result[0])
    )
});
```

---

Side note: That code breaks one of the Rules of Promises, which is:

> Handle rejection, or pass the promise chain to something that will.

You probably want to add a rejection handler via `.catch`.

Side note 2: Assuming `fetch` is the standard [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch), your code is missing a check for success. This is a footgun in the `fetch` API (I write about it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)). Fixing it:

```
    Promise.all(
        urls.map(u=>fetch(u).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return res.json();
        }))
    ).then(texts => {
```

Note that that eliminates the need for the second `Promise.all` as well, but handling each `fetch` individually earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The first result works perfectly!

Comment: Also, your point about the rejection handling is appreciated, I will implement that

Comment: @megadarkfriend - My pleasure! I've added another note as well. :-)

Comment: I would comment on that article, but since most comments there are spam it might not get noticed.  There is a typo in the first line of the definition of `myFetch` -- a missing `)`.

Comment: Is there a reason (besides that it was in the original) for the nested `Promise.all`?  I would just do `Promise .all (urls .map (u => fetch (u) .then (res => res .json ()))) .then (...)`, subject of course to your suggestion of using a better version of `fetch`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - See the update at the end, I removed it there. :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Thanks for the head's up on the typo! Er, um, I mean...what typo? There's no typo in that code... ;-) (Also thanks for mentioning the comments. I guess however it was I used to get notified of comments has been switched off. :-| )